# Prevent user from switching to other windows

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-services, window

I want to allow my user to work with only a few predefined list of applications during a certain time. I'm using a C# Windows Service that will run in the background and check the active window during a specific time period to verify that the active application is in the list of allowed apps.

I have done some homework and it looks like I need to capture "*window switch*" event through `SetWinEventHook()` and then call `SwitchToThisWindow()` or `SetActiveWindow()` to switch back in case the new window is not allowed.

But this doesn't really work. I'm still able to switch to other windows.

What am I doing wrong, or even if I'm taking the correct approach?

Comment: Can we see the code you've attempted?

Comment: This isn't going to work. Windows Services do not run on the user's desktop, so they have no idea what windows they have open. You don't want a service. And writing an app is the completely wrong way to solve this problem in the first place. Windows has built-in security features to lock down a machine. Investigate making use of Group Policy; ask more questions about that on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Is this to build a custom application machine and/or a web kiosk type system?  You might want to look at Windows XP Embedded where you can remove the explorer and the ability to run any apps other than what you want.  It's specifically designed for the scenario you are describing.